# I need a Selenium XPath solution, targeting the Edit link by the FB0488 div

Tags: html, xpath

I tried div/span[text()='Edit']//follow-sibling::div[text()='FB0488']...I just don't get this following sibling stuff yet. Here's a snippet of the html:

```
<div class="rt-td" role="gridcell" style="flex: 50 0 auto; width: 50px; max-width: 50px;"><span class=" clickable btn-link font-weight-bold">Edit</span></div>
<div class="rt-td" role="gridcell" style="flex: 70 0 auto; width: 70px; max-width: 70px;">FB0488</div>
<div class="rt-td" role="gridcell" style="flex: 90 0 auto; width: 90px; max-width: 90px;">I</div>
<div class="rt-td" role="gridcell" style="flex: 150 0 auto; width: 150px; max-width: 150px;">19 May 2022/20:20</div>
```

Comment: <div class="rt-td" role="gridcell" style="flex: 50 0 auto; width: 50px; max-width: 50px;"><span class=" clickable btn-link font-weight-bold">Edit</span></div><div class="rt-td" role="gridcell" style="flex: 70 0 auto; width: 70px; max-width: 70px;">FB0488</div><div class="rt-td" role="gridcell" style="flex: 90 0 auto; width: 90px; max-width: 90px;">I</div>

Comment: Can you edit your question, move the stuff from the comment to the body of the question, make sure it's properly formatted and add your exact expected output?

Comment: And it is not follow-sibling but following-sibling

Answer (score 0):

You tried to get the [`following-sibling`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-following-sibling-in-selenium) on the `span`-element, but it should be the `div`-element.

To do that you have to create the predicate on the `div`-element like this

```
//div[span[text()='Edit']]/following-sibling::div[text()='FB0488']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try //div[span[text()='Edit']]//ancestor::div[text()='FB0488']